# synchronise scroll of two react components without using state and actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to sync scroll of two different components in React so that if I scroll one in one component the other component will also scroll. The two are in different ratios so I have to calculate to offsets every time.

I don't want to use state and actions (I am using redux) since it hurts my performance due to re-rendering every mouse scroll (I also tried debouncing/throttling).

I have a wrapper component which renders two other components like so:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FirstComponent />
        <SecondComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use `ref` but it doesn't work on custom components (I get `undefined`) and in any case this all looks like an anti-pattern for react/redux.

Any suggestion on how to achieve that without hurting performance and staying as close as possible to the React/Redux patterns?

Answer (score 7):

For similar questions in the future you can look at: [react-scroll-sync](https://github.com/okonet/react-scroll-sync), which saved my work with very complex table syncing case.

A short example how to use:

```
<ScrollSync>
<div style={{ display: 'flex', position: 'relative', height: 300 }}>
  <ScrollSyncPane>
    <div style={{overflow: 'auto'}}>
      <section style={{ height: 500 }}>
        <h1>Left Pane Content</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab aperiam doloribus
          dolorum
          est eum eveniet exercitationem iste labore minus, neque nobis odit officiis omnis
          possimus quasi rerum sed soluta veritatis.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </ScrollSyncPane>

  <ScrollSyncPane>
    <div style={{overflow: 'auto'}}>
      <section style={{ height: 1000 }}>
        <h1>Middle Pane Content</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab aperiam doloribus
          dolorum
          est eum eveniet exercitationem iste labore minus, neque nobis odit officiis omnis
          possimus quasi rerum sed soluta veritatis.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </ScrollSyncPane>

</div>
</ScrollSync>
```

Comment: I forked the react-sync-scroll library into a hook so you can reduce the boilerplate in your jsx: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-sync-hook

Answer (score 6):

React. **Sync 2 div or table scrolls**. Without state, actions and third party libraries. My **solution is**:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
const firstDivRef = useRef();
const secondDivRef = useRef();

const handleScrollFirst = scroll => {
  secondDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
};

const handleScrollSecond = scroll => {
  firstDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
};

return (
<div>
  <div onScroll={handleScrollFirst} ref={firstDivRef}>
    The first div (or it can be tbody of a table and etc.)
  </div>

  <div onScroll={handleScrollSecond} ref={secondDivRef}>
    The second div
  </div>
</div>
);
};
```

**It won't work without some styling**. Please check the full version below to check the styled version

**Live Demo**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-scroll-sync-of-2-divs-10xpi

**That's it!** :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created [this library](https://github.com/AhmadMHawwash/scroll-sync-react) recently, that solves your issue

All you need is to:

1. make `<ScrollSync>` as a common parent to your nodes you want to sync scroll with other nodes (which is a React component that uses React's new Context API)
2. and then wrap each scrollable-node with a `<ScrollSyncNode>`

and then the sync happens :D

check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-sky-joiou)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, React doesn't have a good solution for DOM manipulation beyond refs, and you're absolutely right that you don't want to provoke re-renders after each event.

Using `ref` should absolutely work, but keep in mind that it may sometimes return `undefined` at least until the mount occurs, so you'll need to simply handle the situation where it doesn't exist yet.